# Unable to see appium-webdriveragent folder when install Appium 2.0

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I have installed Appium 2.0 using command line but unable to see the appium-webdriveragent folder under **/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/** path (no folder found which is starts with appium).

**Theses are the following commands I ran:**
npm install -g appium@next
brew install Carthage
npm install -g appium-doctor
appium --base-path /wd/hub
appium driver install xcuitest
appium plugin install images
appium plugin install execute-driver
appium plugin install relaxed-caps

**This is the appium version:**
~ % appium -v
2.0.0-beta.46

**This is the driver installed location:**
~ % npm ls -g appium-webdriveragent
/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)

**I am using Xcode:**
Version 14.1 (14B47b)

**This is the execution failure log:**
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. **Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: xcodebuild failed with code 65**
xcodebuild error message:
. Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
Host info: host: 'L0057s-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1863:fbc8:e2f5:1313%en0'
Build info: version: '4.5.0', revision: 'fe167b119a'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.5.1', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{appium:appName=XXXX APP, appium:automationName=XCUITest, browserName=, appium:deviceName=iPhone 6s, appium:newCommandTimeout=60, platformName=IOS, appium:platformVersion=15.7.1, appium:udid=0ee9ce6c7e262203d06348ed55de4e747cfaab75, appium:usePrebuiltWDA=true}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {appName: XXXX APP, automationName: XCUITest, browserName: , deviceName: iPhone 6s, newCommandTimeout: 60, platformName: IOS, platformVersion: 15.7.1, udid: XXXXXXXX1234..., usePrebuiltWDA: true}}]
Capabilities {}

have followed https://github.com/appium/appium

Comment: What do you get when you do "which appium" in the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing XCUITest via:

```
appium driver install xcuitest or appium driver update xcuitest
```

appium-webdriveragent folder is available in user's home directory as .appium or can be located via

```
echo "$(dirname "$(find "$HOME/.appium" -name WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj)")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this fix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TprXEKBnfmA).
For me it didn't work and I had to go back to xcode 13.4.1 to have it working again...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the fix video, may be it will helpful if I have webdriveragent folder. My problem is I don't see the webdriveragent folder anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as well with Appium2 (2.0.0-beta.46) but, unfortunately, I had to go back to 1.22.3 and downgraded Xcode from 14.1 to 13.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the place where my response should be, but tried to get Webdiveragent installed in target device and after looking in different places for a solution, the only thing that worked was to **downgrade** from XCode 14.2 to **13.4.1**.

Now I'm on:
MacOS 12.6.3.
Appium 2.0.0-beta.61.
XCode 13.4.1